Average of interval data type in jOOQ
We have two columns in a table the_table, first and second. These columns have the data type of timestamp without time zone, which translates to LocalDateTime in the generator.
The generated table class is THE_TABLE and it's properties are FIRST and SECOND.
In the native SQL, we would like to do the following.
SELECT 
  avg(THE_TABLE.SECOND - THE_TABLE.FIRST) "average_time_taken"
FROM THE_TABLE;

The resulting "average_time_taken" column is a duration.
Trying to reproduce a similar SQL with jOOQ,
dsl
  .select(
    avg(THE_TABLE.SECOND.minus(THE_TABLE.FIRST))
  )
  .from(THE_TABLE)
  .fetchOne()
  ...

but the call to avg(THE_TABLE.SECOND.minus(THE_TABLE.FIRST)) is failing to compile with the following.

Type mismatch.
Required: Field<out Number!>!
Found: Field<LocalDateTime!>

What's the solution?
The documentation suggests the INTERVAL data types extend java.lang.Number, which should allow us to perform such calculations, but I suppose there is something not right with the types in the generated code.

For every date / time type, there is a *_diff function in jOOQ.
The solution is,
..
  avg(
    localDateTimeDiff(THE_TABLE.SECOND, THE_TABLE.FIRST)
  )
..

The functions in *_diff pattern would return Interval types, which extends java.lang.Number and you can use them with avg, max or other functions.
